# Drawing a line in a UIView subview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiview, core-graphics

I have a UIView subclass. This subclass has multiple subviews. Is it possible to draw a line using core graphics inside a subview that is part of the uiview subclass?

For example, I have a SampleView class, which is a subclass of UIView. Inside this class's header file is the property for UIView *sampleSubView, which is a subview of SampleView. Is it possible to draw a line inside of sampleSubView from the SampleView class implementation?

Thanks for your help!
Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking how a UIView subclass can draw a line on itself, then see the [Quartz demo sample code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html).  Basically, you'll override the view's `drawRect:` method, get the current graphics context, then draw whatever you like onto it.

If you are asking how one view can draw a line on another view, perhaps you need to rethink your architecture.

Comment: The way I'm going to solve this is to have another custom UIView (the subview) have methods to draw lines rather than worry about a hierarchy, thanks for your answer.